# Any method for measuring hydroxyl and hydroperoxyl radicals in water?

Tags: radicals, radiochemistry

I am looking to irradiate water containing some amounts of iron and would like to measure the amount of hydroperoxyl and hydroxyl radicals produced in real time as a result of the irradiation. Is there any way to do so without very expensive equipment such as an EPR machine?

Answer (score 2):

There are various colorimetric methods to measure peroxide production, and since you plan to have iron in solution, "the chromogenic $\ce{Fe+++}$-xylenol orange reaction, in which a purple complex is formed when $\ce{Fe++}$ provided in the reagent is oxidized to $\ce{Fe+++}$ by peroxides present in the sample," would seem to be ideal for your purpose, as suggested by [BioAssay System](https://bioassaysys.com/peroxide-assay-kit/). Another test uses Amplex™ Red reagent (10-acetyl-3,7-dihydroxyphenoxazine) and a peroxidase to create easily detected light -- but during irradiation, it might be confused with [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).

As for hydroxyl measurement, if offset by hydronium production, then pH would not change -- but *conductivity* might. However, *measuring* such a small change in an otherwise conductive solution with dissolved salts might be tricky. You might test  [pH indicators](https://sciencenotes.org/ph-indicator-chart-colors-and-ranges/) to see if there is any noticeable change, but I'd not be sanguine about that.